# CNN model in python Facial Recognition raises runtime error when dlib and cuda are properly installed

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

The facial recognition package has two samples: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/find_faces_in_picture.py and https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/find_faces_in_picture_cnn.py

After following the tutorial from https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#installation and installing dlib from https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/629d75c1baac34dfa5ca2a1928a7aeaf prior to the installation of face_recognition (import dlib works), the code sample in the first link provided works fine:

```
import face_recognition

image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama.jpg")

face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

top, right, bottom, left = face_locations[0]
face_image = image[top:bottom, left:right]
pil_image = Image.fromarray(face_image)
pil_image
```

However if `face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)` is changed to `face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image, model='cnn')`, a runtime error is raised:

```
RuntimeError: Error while calling cudnnSetConvolution2dDescriptor((cudnnConvolutionDescriptor_t)conv_handle, padding_y, padding_x, stride_y, stride_x, 1, 1, CUDNN_CROSS_CORRELATION) in file /tmp/pip-build-gl2dutj1/dlib/dlib/cuda/cudnn_dlibapi.cpp:826. code: 3, reason: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
```

This https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/867 github issue describes a similar problem but has no solution. Similarly this https://github.com/natanielruiz/deep-head-pose/issues/7 issue describes a similar problem but it says to just build from the source which I did.

dlib is using cuda as

```
import dlib

dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA
```

Returns True. Unlike [Dlib (GPU supported) is not working properly, not sure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713466/dlib-gpu-supported-is-not-working-properly-not-sure), it always raises this runtime error, even after restarting the jupyter kernel (64gb of RAM on my system, highly doubt a memory issue).